# Move from App Engine Flex to App Engine Standard Second Generation

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to move from App engine flex to standard second generation.

I have deployed my code as a docker on AE Flex environment where I even need to install system libraries(zbar-tools, libzbar-dev, ImageMagick), which are not available by default in the standard environment. I have made a few changes to the default parameters of a system library(it had to be done).

How can I perform the same operations related to system libraries in AE second generation environment? If I cannot deploy it as a docker

I did try [deploying](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15cokq_AWPKFERlbjBRWpif-ae5hYBZuv/view?usp=sharing) my docker on AE second generation(by changing the runtime parameter), it crashed

Thanks